# Ask user for a confirmation from chrome extension manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with manifest v2 which works fine.
At one point I need to ask the user for a confirmation and doing so by confirm.

The example code.

```
//Manifest v2 working background script 
function myFunction(){
  if (confirm("Going to update")){ 
      updateIssue = true;
  }else{
     return;
  }

  if(updateIssue){
    //do my stuff
  }

}
```

For the migration to manifest v3 I need to replace confirm with something as it is not working anymore. I tried chrome.runtime.executeScript, but this will not wait for the user click before going on in the script. Have not found a standard way/alternative for confirm() in chrome extension?

```
function myFunction(){
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    function: () => {
       if (confirm("Bla und Blub")){
          updateIssue = true;
       }else{
          return;
       };
     }
     });

  if (updateIssue){
    //do my stuff, 
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `confirm()` inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).

manifest.json:

```json
  "permissions": ["offscreen", "storage"],
```

background.js

```js
async function myFunction() {
  if (await runOffscreen(['confirm', 'Please confirm blabla'])) {
    //do my stuff, 
  }
}
async function runOffscreen(msg, url = 'offscreen.html') {
  url = chrome.runtime.getURL(url);
  await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
    url,
    reasons: ['DOM_SCRAPING'],
    justification: 'confirm',
  }).catch(() => {});
  const doc = (await clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true}))
    .find(c => c.url === url);
  const mc = new MessageChannel();
  doc.postMessage(msg, [mc.port2]);
  const res = await new Promise(cb => { mc.port1.onmessage = cb; });
  await chrome.offscreen.closeDocument();
  return res.data;
}
```

offscreen.html:

```html
<script src=offscreen.js></script>
```

offscreen.js:

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = ({data: [cmd, arg], ports}) => {
  if (cmd === 'confirm') ports[0].postMessage(confirm(arg));
};
```

P.S. Regarding executeScript: the function runs in the context of the web page tab, so it can't access stuff outside its own scope. You need to return the value from the function and use the result:

```js
async function myFunction() {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  const [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    func: () => confirm('Bla und Blub'),
  });
  if (result) { /* do stuff */ }
}
```